# Don't want the excess tag in my FOR XML Path('td')

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, for-xml

I'm looking for an XML output like this:

```
<td id="1">123</td>
```

My current SQL statment:

```
SELECT EmpID AS "@ID", EmpNo FROM Employees FOR XML PATH('td')
```

Which gets me this:

```
<td id="1"><EmpNo>123</EmpNo></td>
```

All I'm looking to do is remove the EmpNo tag as it is not needed. I'm sure there is a very simple method for doing this but for the life of me I can't find it. I think I've been searching too long... time for a coffee.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

JT...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want like this:

```
SELECT EmpID "td/@id", EmpNo "td" 
FROM Employees 
FOR XML PATH('')
```

Comment: the double quotes should be single quotes.

Comment: Forget last comment. Yep this works a treat... Cheers mate I owe ya one.

Comment: @James Jiao, double quotes are used to quote identifiers, single quotes are used to quote strings.  Double quotes around identifiers that have invalid characters, in this case `/` and `@`, are correct.